# keep page 100% when zooming into iframe content on touch device

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, responsive-design

I have a page that displays a container div and next to it is an iframe that is displaying an model I made using "Three.js" which works perfectly. The problem I have is when I switch this over to my touch device and interact with the model(by zooming in), the whole page zooms in instead of the model itself. I've been researching and all the solutions i've found didn't fix my bug. Basically, all I want is for the model(inside the iframe) itself to zoom in/out when on touch device and not the whole screen. I believe the problem has to deal with th model itself because when I switch the model from a regular gltf file to a pointmaterial it works fine. Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
          <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
              <div class="sidebar-sticky">

                  <h1>text</h1>
                    <p>text </p>

   </div>
                  <!--sticky footer-->
          <footer class="footer">
              <div >
                          <p align="center"><a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="es/test.html">spanish</a><br>
                          <!--<p>This interactive was made possible through the support of</p>-->
                          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:100%" /></a></p>

                      </div>

                  </footer>

           </nav>
  </div>
        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-12 px-0">

            <!-- Featured Content  -->

              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" onload="onload="redirect();">


                      <iframe style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none;
                   margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:1;" class="embed-responsive-item" src="models/page.html" allowfullscreen></iframe>


              </div>

        </main>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#width{

    width: 600px;

}
body{

    overflow: hidden;
}
body p {
    font-size: .875em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family:'Marcellus';
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.feather {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/*sticky-footer*/

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 100px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    /*line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
    /*padding: 20px;*/
    background-color: #F8F9FA;
}


/*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; /* Height of navbar */
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
  /* height: 90%; */
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a ThreeJS question. What you're looking for is the CSS `touch-action` attribute to prevent pinch-zooming on touch devices. Try adding `touch-action: none;` to your iframe, and it will prevent the user from zooming in when pinching this iframe.

For more info, see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#auto).